# How to view all Facebook comments I have made on news websites, blogs, etc.?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I would like to **view** all Facebook comments I have made on news websites, blogs, etc., which use the Facebook Comments Plugin.

I had tried `Activity Log` → `Filter` → `Comments`, and I can only see a list of activity logs of my commenting in the left sidebar and cannot **view** the content of the comments. Clicking an activity log of my commenting does nothing. And clicking a "three dots" menu icon, which appears when I hover my mouse cursor over an activity log of my commenting, shows only one option: `Delete`.

How do I actually **view** my comments I have made on those websites?

I need to edit some of those comments of mine.